# Undefined reference to my function

Tags: postgresql, functions, errors

I'm working on a project on postgresql 8.4 server side. I'm adding some functionality in order to store some query informations.

I need to call two functions (start_create_profile() and check()) inside of `exec_simple_query` in `postgres.c`
These functions are written by me in a file called test.c in `/src/backend/utils/misc`. I also written the library test.h  is in `/src/include/utils/`

I'm using eclipse as IDE and I'm getting the proble:

```
undefined reference to `start_create_profile'   /pgsql/src/backend/tcop postgres.c C/C++ Problem
```

I don't understand where is my mistake

The test.c is

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "utils/progProfile.h"
#include "nodes/pg_list.h"
#include <libpq-fe.h>

void start_create_profile(List *querytree_list){

    ListCell *l;
    ListCell *tl;
    FILE *f;

    //if the file exist just open and write
    //else create and write
    f = fopen ("QueryParsed.txt", "a+");

    Query *query_idr = (Query *)linitial(querytree_list);

    // CMD_SELECT=0 CMD_INSERT=1 CMD_UPDATE=2
    switch (query_idr->commandType)
    {
        case CMD_SELECT:
            fputs("CMD_SELECT, ", f);
        break;

        case CMD_INSERT:
            fputs("CMD_INSERT, ", f);
            break;

        case CMD_UPDATE:
            fputs("CMD_UPDATE, ", f);
        break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    //to have the ID of the table
    foreach(l, query_idr->rtable){
        Oid tab_idT = ((RangeTblEntry *) lfirst(l)) ->relid;
        char temp1[10];
        char *tab_idTConverted = itoa(tab_idT, temp1);
        /* This is not a table */
        if (tab_idT == 0)
            continue;

        fputs(" tab_id:  , ", f);
        fputs(tab_idTConverted, f);

    }

    //to have the name of the targer list
    foreach(tl, query_idr->targetList){
        TargetEntry *tle = (TargetEntry *) lfirst(tl);
        Oid tab_id = tle->resorigtbl;
        int tab_idCast=(int)tab_id;
        char temp[10];
        char *tab_idConverted = itoa(tab_idCast, temp);
        char *resname=tle->resname;

        fputs("Name of column:  ", f);
        fputs(resname, f);
        fputs(" ID:  ", f);
        fputs(tab_idConverted, f);
        fputs("\n", f);
    }

    //close the file that we write
    fputs("$", f);
    fclose (f);
}


static char* itoa(int n, char s[])
{
    int i, sign;
    if ((sign = n) < 0)
        n = -n;
    i = 0;
    do
    {
      s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';
    } while ((n /= 10) > 0);

    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';

    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);

    return s;
}

static void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i, j;
    char c;

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
}
```

test.h is

```
bool TrainingFinished=1;

typedef struct Profile{
    List *subProfile;
    char *nameProgram;
}Profile;

typedef struct SubProfile{
    List *input;
    char *command;
    char *columnName;
    int table;
}SubProfile;



/* interfaces */
extern void start_create_profile(List *querytree_list);
extern void create_profile();
extern void check_anomaly(List *querytree_list);
```

and in postgres.c in exec_simple_query I had added:

```
            start_create_profile(querytree_list);
```

that is after these postgresql command:

```
/*
 * OK to analyze, rewrite, and plan this query.
 *
 * Switch to appropriate context for constructing querytrees (again,
 * these must outlive the execution context).
 */
oldcontext = MemoryContextSwitchTo(MessageContext);

querytree_list = pg_analyze_and_rewrite(parsetree, query_string,
                                        NULL, 0);
```

The header of postgres.c

```
#include "postgres.h"

#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H
#include <sys/select.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_RESOURCE_H
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_GETOPT_H
#include <getopt.h>
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_GETRUSAGE
#include "rusagestub.h"
#endif

#include "access/printtup.h"
#include "access/xact.h"
#include "catalog/pg_type.h"
#include "commands/async.h"
#include "commands/prepare.h"
#include "libpq/libpq.h"
#include "libpq/pqformat.h"
#include "libpq/pqsignal.h"
#include "miscadmin.h"
#include "nodes/print.h"
#include "optimizer/planner.h"
#include "pgstat.h"
#include "pg_trace.h"
#include "parser/analyze.h"
#include "parser/parser.h"
#include "postmaster/autovacuum.h"
#include "rewrite/rewriteHandler.h"
#include "storage/bufmgr.h"
#include "storage/ipc.h"
#include "storage/proc.h"
#include "storage/sinval.h"
#include "tcop/fastpath.h"
#include "tcop/pquery.h"
#include "tcop/tcopprot.h"
#include "tcop/utility.h"
#include "utils/flatfiles.h"
#include "utils/lsyscache.h"
#include "utils/memutils.h"
#include "utils/ps_status.h"
#include "utils/snapmgr.h"
#include "mb/pg_wchar.h"

/* Mine */
#include <utils/progProfile.h>
```

This is the exec_simple_query

```
/*
 * exec_simple_query
 *
 * Execute a "simple Query" protocol message.
 */
static void
exec_simple_query(const char *query_string)
{
    CommandDest dest = whereToSendOutput;
    MemoryContext oldcontext;
    List       *parsetree_list;
    ListCell   *parsetree_item;
    bool        save_log_statement_stats = log_statement_stats;
    bool        was_logged = false;
    bool        isTopLevel;
    char        msec_str[32];


    /*
     * Report query to various monitoring facilities.
     */
    debug_query_string = query_string;

    pgstat_report_activity(query_string);

    TRACE_POSTGRESQL_QUERY_START(query_string);

    /*
     * We use save_log_statement_stats so ShowUsage doesn't report incorrect
     * results because ResetUsage wasn't called.
     */
    if (save_log_statement_stats)
        ResetUsage();

    /*
     * Start up a transaction command.  All queries generated by the
     * query_string will be in this same command block, *unless* we find a
     * BEGIN/COMMIT/ABORT statement; we have to force a new xact command after
     * one of those, else bad things will happen in xact.c. (Note that this
     * will normally change current memory context.)
     */
    start_xact_command();

    /*
     * Zap any pre-existing unnamed statement.  (While not strictly necessary,
     * it seems best to define simple-Query mode as if it used the unnamed
     * statement and portal; this ensures we recover any storage used by prior
     * unnamed operations.)
     */
    drop_unnamed_stmt();

    /*
     * Switch to appropriate context for constructing parsetrees.
     */
    oldcontext = MemoryContextSwitchTo(MessageContext);

    /*
     * Do basic parsing of the query or queries (this should be safe even if
     * we are in aborted transaction state!)
     */
    parsetree_list = pg_parse_query(query_string);

    /* Log immediately if dictated by log_statement */
    if (check_log_statement(parsetree_list))
    {
        ereport(LOG,
                (errmsg("statement: %s", query_string),
                 errhidestmt(true),
                 errdetail_execute(parsetree_list)));
        was_logged = true;
    }

    /*
     * Switch back to transaction context to enter the loop.
     */
    MemoryContextSwitchTo(oldcontext);

    /*
     * We'll tell PortalRun it's a top-level command iff there's exactly one
     * raw parsetree.  If more than one, it's effectively a transaction block
     * and we want PreventTransactionChain to reject unsafe commands. (Note:
     * we're assuming that query rewrite cannot add commands that are
     * significant to PreventTransactionChain.)
     */
    isTopLevel = (list_length(parsetree_list) == 1);

    /*
     * Run through the raw parsetree(s) and process each one.
     */
    foreach(parsetree_item, parsetree_list)
    {
        Node       *parsetree = (Node *) lfirst(parsetree_item);
        bool        snapshot_set = false;
        const char *commandTag;
        char        completionTag[COMPLETION_TAG_BUFSIZE];
        List       *querytree_list,
                   *plantree_list;
        Portal      portal;
        DestReceiver *receiver;
        int16       format;

        /*
         * Get the command name for use in status display (it also becomes the
         * default completion tag, down inside PortalRun).  Set ps_status and
         * do any special start-of-SQL-command processing needed by the
         * destination.
         */
        commandTag = CreateCommandTag(parsetree);

        set_ps_display(commandTag, false);

        BeginCommand(commandTag, dest);

        /*
         * If we are in an aborted transaction, reject all commands except
         * COMMIT/ABORT.  It is important that this test occur before we try
         * to do parse analysis, rewrite, or planning, since all those phases
         * try to do database accesses, which may fail in abort state. (It
         * might be safe to allow some additional utility commands in this
         * state, but not many...)
         */
        if (IsAbortedTransactionBlockState() &&
            !IsTransactionExitStmt(parsetree))
            ereport(ERROR,
                    (errcode(ERRCODE_IN_FAILED_SQL_TRANSACTION),
                     errmsg("current transaction is aborted, "
                        "commands ignored until end of transaction block")));

        /* Make sure we are in a transaction command */
        start_xact_command();

        /* If we got a cancel signal in parsing or prior command, quit */
        CHECK_FOR_INTERRUPTS();

        /*
         * Set up a snapshot if parse analysis/planning will need one.
         */
        if (analyze_requires_snapshot(parsetree))
        {
            PushActiveSnapshot(GetTransactionSnapshot());
            snapshot_set = true;
        }

        /*
         * OK to analyze, rewrite, and plan this query.
         *
         * Switch to appropriate context for constructing querytrees (again,
         * these must outlive the execution context).
         */
        oldcontext = MemoryContextSwitchTo(MessageContext);

        querytree_list = pg_analyze_and_rewrite(parsetree, query_string,
                                                NULL, 0);


        /*********** Mine **********/

            start_create_profile(querytree_list);

        /*********** Mine **********/

        plantree_list = pg_plan_queries(querytree_list, 0, NULL);

        /* Done with the snapshot used for parsing/planning */
        if (snapshot_set)
            PopActiveSnapshot();

        /* If we got a cancel signal in analysis or planning, quit */
        CHECK_FOR_INTERRUPTS();

        /*
         * Create unnamed portal to run the query or queries in. If there
         * already is one, silently drop it.
         */
        portal = CreatePortal("", true, true);
        /* Don't display the portal in pg_cursors */
        portal->visible = false;

        /*
         * We don't have to copy anything into the portal, because everything
         * we are passing here is in MessageContext, which will outlive the
         * portal anyway.
         */
        PortalDefineQuery(portal,
                          NULL,
                          query_string,
                          commandTag,
                          plantree_list,
                          NULL);

        /*
         * Start the portal.  No parameters here.
         */
        PortalStart(portal, NULL, InvalidSnapshot);

        /*
         * Select the appropriate output format: text unless we are doing a
         * FETCH from a binary cursor.  (Pretty grotty to have to do this here
         * --- but it avoids grottiness in other places.  Ah, the joys of
         * backward compatibility...)
         */
        format = 0;             /* TEXT is default */
        if (IsA(parsetree, FetchStmt))
        {
            FetchStmt  *stmt = (FetchStmt *) parsetree;

            if (!stmt->ismove)
            {
                Portal      fportal = GetPortalByName(stmt->portalname);

                if (PortalIsValid(fportal) &&
                    (fportal->cursorOptions & CURSOR_OPT_BINARY))
                    format = 1; /* BINARY */
            }
        }
        PortalSetResultFormat(portal, 1, &format);

        /*
         * Now we can create the destination receiver object.
         */
        receiver = CreateDestReceiver(dest);
        if (dest == DestRemote)
            SetRemoteDestReceiverParams(receiver, portal);

        /*
         * Switch back to transaction context for execution.
         */
        MemoryContextSwitchTo(oldcontext);

        /*
         * Run the portal to completion, and then drop it (and the receiver).
         */
        (void) PortalRun(portal,
                         FETCH_ALL,
                         isTopLevel,
                         receiver,
                         receiver,
                         completionTag);

        (*receiver->rDestroy) (receiver);

        PortalDrop(portal, false);

        if (IsA(parsetree, TransactionStmt))
        {
            /*
             * If this was a transaction control statement, commit it. We will
             * start a new xact command for the next command (if any).
             */
            finish_xact_command();
        }
        else if (lnext(parsetree_item) == NULL)
        {
            /*
             * If this is the last parsetree of the query string, close down
             * transaction statement before reporting command-complete.  This
             * is so that any end-of-transaction errors are reported before
             * the command-complete message is issued, to avoid confusing
             * clients who will expect either a command-complete message or an
             * error, not one and then the other.  But for compatibility with
             * historical Postgres behavior, we do not force a transaction
             * boundary between queries appearing in a single query string.
             */
            finish_xact_command();
        }
        else
        {
            /*
             * We need a CommandCounterIncrement after every query, except
             * those that start or end a transaction block.
             */
            CommandCounterIncrement();
        }

        /*
         * Tell client that we're done with this query.  Note we emit exactly
         * one EndCommand report for each raw parsetree, thus one for each SQL
         * command the client sent, regardless of rewriting. (But a command
         * aborted by error will not send an EndCommand report at all.)
         */
        EndCommand(completionTag, dest);
    }                           /* end loop over parsetrees */

    /*
     * Close down transaction statement, if one is open.
     */
    finish_xact_command();

    /*
     * If there were no parsetrees, return EmptyQueryResponse message.
     */
    if (!parsetree_list)
        NullCommand(dest);

    /*
     * Emit duration logging if appropriate.
     */
    switch (check_log_duration(msec_str, was_logged))
    {
        case 1:
            ereport(LOG,
                    (errmsg("duration: %s ms", msec_str),
                     errhidestmt(true)));
            break;
        case 2:
            ereport(LOG,
                    (errmsg("duration: %s ms  statement: %s",
                            msec_str, query_string),
                     errhidestmt(true),
                     errdetail_execute(parsetree_list)));
            break;
    }

    if (save_log_statement_stats)
        ShowUsage("QUERY STATISTICS");

    TRACE_POSTGRESQL_QUERY_DONE(query_string);

    debug_query_string = NULL;
}
```

Comment: And how do we know without seeing your code? :)

Comment: Also what was the process used to build/link them?

Comment: @dezso sorry, you're right, I've edited the question.

Comment: @ChrisTravers I build them with the building inside of eclipse. What do you mean with link?

Comment: Could you also show the headers of postgres.c and the whole call?

Comment: @dezso I edited the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this on compilation or on trying to import this into PostgreSQL as a function?

Comment: Are you compiling using `pgxs` ? If you're not, do so.

Comment: @ChrisTravers Yes, in compilation

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm using eclipse as a IDE and I compile inside that. What is pgxs? How can I use pgxs?

Comment: Re-reading it looks like you're compiling the whole server. I initially thought you were just compiling an extension. If you're building the server use the standard build system (`configure`, `make`, etc for unix, or the `src/tools/msvc/` dir for Windows). If you're building an extension use pgxs. In both cases, read the manual for details. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-procedure.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-windows.html

Comment: Also, "What do you mean with link". Um. http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html .

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are almost certainly missing a declaration and function prototype for the function.  It looks to me like you trying to hack the PostgreSQL source to provide the execution of a function you have coded at a certain point, but you aren't able to compile the back-end because the function prototype is not found.  This means you need to add the function declaration/prototype to the relevant header file as well.

At this point standard C troubleshooting applies, so check header files, check function declarations and prototypes, etc.  That will probably solve this specific issue.